# How can I groupby a DataFrame at the same time I count the values and put in different columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a DataFrame that looks like the one below

```
Index  Category  Class
 0        1        A
 1        1        A
 2        1        B
 3        2        A
 4        3        B
 5        3        B
```

And I would like to get an output data frame that groups by category and have one column for each of the classes with the counting of the occurrences of that class in each category, such as the one below

```
Index Category   A   B
 0      1        2   1
 1      2        1   0
 2      3        0   2
```

So far I've tried various combinations of the `groupby` and `agg` methods, but I still can't get what I want. I've also tried `df.pivot_table(index='Category', columns='Class', aggfunc='count')`, but that return a DataFrame without columns. Any ideas of what could work in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `aggfunc="size"` to achieve your desired result:

```
>>> df.pivot_table(index='Category', columns='Class', aggfunc='size', fill_value=0)

Class     A  B
Category
1         2  1
2         1  0
3         0  2
```

Alternatively, you can use `.groupby(...).size()` to get the counts, and then unstack to reshape your data as well:

```
>>> df.groupby(["Category", "Class"]).size().unstack(fill_value=0)

Class     A  B
Category
1         2  1
2         1  0
3         0  2
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign a dummy value to count:

```
out = df.assign(val=1).pivot_table('val', 'Category', 'Class',
                                   aggfunc='count', fill_value=0).reset_index()
print(out)

# Output
Class  Category  A  B
0             1  2  1
1             2  1  0
2             3  0  2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Index':[0,1,2,3,4,5],
                   'Category': [1,1,1,2,3,3],
                   'Class':['A','A','B','A','B','B'],
              })
df = df.groupby(['Category', 'Class']).count()
df = df.pivot_table(index='Category', columns='Class')
print(df)
```

output:

```
             Index     
Class        A    B
Category           
1          2.0  1.0
2          1.0  NaN
3          NaN  2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
pd.crosstab(df['Category'], df['Class']).reset_index()
```

output:

```
Class  Category  A  B
0             1  2  1
1             2  1  0
2             3  0  2
```